# JMC / JavaFX - Playing video

Tags: java, swing, video, javafx

I've tried to create a small application, to just play a video from my hdd. I've tried for 3 days now but I don't know, how to do it. There are no good tutorials or examples on the net, to do this with the current javafx (jmc) release. I wanna create a swing application, that is using the jmc classes from javafx. I tried this:

```
 ...
 MediaProvider mp;
 String mediaURI = "G:\\teste2.avi";
 JFrame jf = new JFrame();

JPanel j = new JPanel();
j.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    mp = new MediaProvider();
    try {
        mp.setSource(new URL("file://" + mediaURI).toURI());
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }catch (URISyntaxException ex2) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex2);
    }

 mp.setRepeating(false);
 j.setSize(800, 600);
 j.setVisible(true);
 jf.add(j);
 jf.setSize(800, 600);
 j.setBackground(Color.red);
 jf.setVisible(true);
 mp.play();
 ...
```

But now: How to add the "mp" to my jpanel? "j.add(mp);" doesn't work (jpanel is red only, because of the color.red, but no video is shown). Is there an easy way to do it? Thank you.

I've also tried with a second class:

```
public class Player implements VideoRendererListener{

private MediaProvider prov; //This is the most important class!

private VideoRenderControl renderer; //It's a interface to control the rendering

private Graphics2D ig;

private JPanel panel;


public void Player(File path, JPanel panel) {
    ig = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
    this.panel = panel;
    prov = new MediaProvider(path.toURI());
    renderer = prov.getControl(VideoRenderControl.class);
    renderer.addVideoRendererListener(this);
    prov.play();
    System.out.println(prov.getDuration());

}

@Override
public void videoFrameUpdated(VideoRendererEvent arg0) {
        float ratio = renderer.getFrameHeight() / (float)renderer.getFrameWidth();

        int diff = ( panel.getHeight() - Math.round(ratio * panel.getHeight())) / 2;

        System.out.println(renderer.getFrameHeight());


      /*  renderer.paintVideo(ig,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, renderer.getFrameWidth(), renderer.getFrameHeight())
                ,
                new Rectangle(0, diff, panel.getWidth(), Math.round(ratio * panel.getHeight())));
*/
}

}
```

and adding this to my jpanel in main class:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.Player(f,j);
```

but the "renderer.paintVideo()" method isn't available :( so also this is not working (maybe with an old version of jmc, because i found this on the internet as example).

Does anyone know, how to add a local video to a swing application with the current release of javafx, jmc ?

Answer (score 1):

I also searching about how to play video and I found this:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1326515&seqNum=4

Check the "Listing 3 XMP2.java" that work for me.

Regards.